# Perform multiple column lookups based on ID

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with several columns:

```
+-------------+----------+------+
|.        id  |      num |cat   |
+-------------+----------+------+
|        00111|     50012|     a|
|        00111|     10131|     a|
|        00111|     11001|     b| 
|        10131|     71010|     a|
|        10131|     60010|     c|
|        11001|     53420|     z|
|        11001|     20011|     a|
|        11001|     00000|     q|
|        13403|     33001|     a|
|        13403|     10023|     a|
|        50012|     00111|     a|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

I would like to do the following:

1. for each unique entry in `id` select ALL values in `num`
2. look up the rows in `id` that match the selected values in `num`
3. select the rows in `cat` that correspond to the `num` values selected and count the number of occurrences of different values.

For example:

1. `id==00111` and `num = [50012; 10131; 11001]`
2. select rows where `id == num`

   ```
   +-------------+----------+------+
   |.        id  |      num |cat   |
   +-------------+----------+------+
   |        10131|     71010|     a|
   |        10131|     60010|     c|
   |        11001|     53420|     z|
   |        11001|     20011|     a|
   |        11001|     00000|     q|
   |        50012|     00111|     a|
   +-------------+----------+------+
   ```
3. select the number of times cat = "a" which would be 3 in this case.
4. repeat for each unique value in `id`

The output would look something like this:

```
+-------------+----------+------+------+
|.        id  |      num |cat   |cat   |
+-------------+----------+------+------+
|        00111|     50012|     a|     3|
|        00111|     10131|     a|     3|
|        00111|     11001|     b|     3|
|        10131|     71010|     a|     1|
|        10131|     60010|     c|     1|
|        11001|     53420|     z|     0|
|        11001|     20011|     a|     0|
|        11001|     00000|     q|     0|
|        13403|     33001|     a|     0|
|        13403|     10023|     a|     0|
|        50012|     00111|     a|     2|
+-------------+----------+------+------+
```

Comment: how would the end output df look like?

Comment: a new column with the number (3 in the above example) displayed for all rows where id==00111 and so on, I added an output example to the original question

Comment: Your first table is `50012| 00111| **p**|` and second table shows "a" for this records. Also, your logic is unclear to me. When `id = 10131`, `num = 71010, 60010`, these numbers in num doesn't appear in `id` but cat count is 1 in your output.  How you are getting the count from?

Comment: @samkart it's because for id = 00111 we select rows:

``|        50012|     00111|     a|     2|
|        10131|     71010|     a|     1|
|        10131|     60010|     c|     1|
|        11001|     53420|     z|     0|
|        11001|     20011|     a|     0|
|        11001|     00000|     q|     0|``


and "a" appears three times in these rows

Comment: thanks @Emma I fixed the issue with *p*. regarding the second question: yes some entries do not have matching elements but they are not included in any counts.

Comment: How you are getting the non-matching elements as cnt=1? For this record in output: `10131 | 71010 | a | 1`.   also why this is cnt=3 `00111 | 11001 | b | 3`?  "b" appears 0 times in 2nd table.

Comment: @Emma for the first question you are correct that is a mistake. for the second one cnt=3 because we are counting the number of times "a" appears in the rows that we looked up for 00111 (i.e. rows 50012, 10131 and 11001). you see 'b" in the final output because that's the value corresponding to 00111 in the original data. basically the "cat" column can be ignored in the final dataset

Comment: maybe this question is way too confusing. I tried to produce a simpler version of the question for the most basic step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675205/selecting-rows-based-on-values-in-another-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

First, map the `num` to `id` with left join, then count when only cat is "a" which has the same id.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id')
df = (df.join(df.select(*[F.col(x).alias(f'{x}_right') for x in df.columns]), 
              on=F.col('num') == F.col('id_right'), how='left')
      .select(*df.columns,
              F.count(F.when(F.col('cat_right') == 'a', 1)).over(w).alias('cnt'))
      .dropDuplicates())
```

Result

```
+-----+-----+---+---+
|   id|  num|cat|cnt|
+-----+-----+---+---+
|00111|50012|  a|  3|
|00111|10131|  a|  3|
|00111|11001|  b|  3|
|10131|71010|  a|  0|
|10131|60010|  c|  0|
|11001|53420|  z|  0|
|11001|20011|  a|  0|
|11001|00000|  q|  0|
|13403|33001|  a|  0|
|13403|10023|  a|  0|
|50012|00111|  a|  2|
+-----+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: I think this is it! I am testing it on the large data I have but for the example it works perfectly. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Join `id` and `num` by self, and just count the `cat`.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id')

df1 = df.drop('cat')
df2 = df.drop('id').withColumnRenamed('num', 'id')
df3 = df1.join(df2, ['id'], 'inner')
df3.show()

df3.withColumn('cnt', f.count(f.when(f.col('cat') == f.lit('a'), True)).over(w)) \
  .show()

+-----+-----+---+
|   id|  num|cat|
+-----+-----+---+
|00111|50012|  p|
|00111|10131|  p|
|00111|11001|  p|
|10131|71010|  a|
|10131|60010|  a|
|11001|53420|  b|
|11001|20011|  b|
|11001|00000|  b|
|50012|00111|  a|
+-----+-----+---+

+-----+-----+---+---+
|   id|  num|cat|cnt|
+-----+-----+---+---+
|00111|50012|  p|  0|
|00111|10131|  p|  0|
|00111|11001|  p|  0|
|10131|71010|  a|  2|
|10131|60010|  a|  2|
|11001|53420|  b|  0|
|11001|20011|  b|  0|
|11001|00000|  b|  0|
|50012|00111|  a|  1|
+-----+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: the general idea looks very promising, but the cnt values don't look right. for id=00111 the cnt value should show 3 since 50012 and 10131 and 11001 all have "a" values in "cat" –