# Selecting rows based on values in another row

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe where the first and second column contain common values:

```
+-------------+----------+------+
|         x   |      y   |z     |
+-------------+----------+------+
|        00111|     50012|     a|
|        00111|     10131|     a|
|        00111|     11001|     b| 
|        50012|     11001|     x|
|        10131|     11001|     z|
|        11001|     50012|     q|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

For each unique value in `x` I want to select the corresponding value in `y` and lookup its rows.

For example for `00111` the corresponding values in y are `50012`, `10131` and `11001`.

this would select:

```
|        50012|     11001|     x|
|        10131|     11001|     z|
|        11001|     50012|     q|
```

I would like to do this for each unique value in x, so the final output would be:

```
|        50012|     11001|     x|
|        10131|     11001|     z|
|        11001|     50012|     q|

|        11001|     50012|     q|

|        11001|     50012|     q|

|        50012|     11001|     x|
```

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/75670230/8279585

Comment: similar indeed, but this is a more general question